# How to abandon Azure App Service session after logging out

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have simple ASP.NET application, which is deployed as Azure App Service. Application has aad as authentication method.

Authentication is configured in Azure Portal with ["Express" management mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings)  (no code for authentication, just portal configuration). Authentication itself is working fine.

Problem is that after logging out from application, server session stays awake and user can have authenticated access to application with previously used `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie value.

Following procedure shows how to access authenticated data with previously saved `AppServiceAuthSession` value.

1. Login to application with aad (browse to `https://[myapp].azurewebsites.net` -> Azure AD login-> no problem)
2. Store value of cookie: `AppServiceAuthSession`
3. Logout by browsing to: `https://[myapp].azurewebsites.net/.auth/logout`
4. Execute http get with previously stored cookie value with following style: `curl --cookie "AppServiceAuthSession=[value]" -X GET https://[myapp].azurewebsites.net`
5. Index page is retrieved with using previously used cookie value.

How to prevent this, and how do I properly abandon all session data when logging out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to "protect" against this.

An attacker has already compromised the user's browser and gotten access to the cookies stored inside. By definition this cookie is a secret that proves that the identity of the HTTP client. If the attacker already has access to it, they can already use it in any number of ways of their choosing that you won't be able to prevent or distinguish from the real user accessing the server legitimately.

The only real solution is using [HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site).

Reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS

Comment: Thanks! After googling while waiting answers, I came up to same conclusion. It also helps that server-side session has some expiration time.